# How to duplicate the current tab in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to duplicate the current tab with its offset to go further in my code investigations but I cannot find a way to do it. I found some videos recommending pressing `Alt` button, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As a related aside:  If you haven't already installed the [Bookmarks](https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-bookmarks) extension in VSCODE, do it right now!  You'll thank me later.

Comment: what do you mean "duplicate"? You mean you want to create a new editor group? (split editor?) And what do you mean by "with its offset"? You mean scroll position?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code version 1.25.1 and later

Way 1

You can simply left click on your file in the side-panel (explorer) and press Ctrl + Enter.

Way 2

Simply right click on your file in the Visual Studio Code side-panel (explorer) and select the first option open to the side.

Comment: Please, be aware that this is not duplicating the tab, but splitting out a new tab. Different things as duplicating the tab allows to make use of the whole editor width.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only split the editor either vertically or horizontally. If you do that, you will have other tab group, so the entire editor width will be divided by the number of groups you create. You can do this by following the two ways indicated by Arabind Coder.